# Sort direction in each column in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sorting, admin, sonata

In the list view, when I first click in the sort button, the default direction is ASC for all the fields. Is there any way to set the direction for each field? Something like:

```
$listMapper
    ->add('name', null, [
        'sort_order' => 'ASC'
    ])
    ->add('date', null, [
        'sort_order' => 'DESC'
    ])
```

Comment: You can only sort on one attribute at the right, right? So how would this look?

Comment: as far as I know: no

Comment: Based on Sonata Admin documentation you can provide only one field for sort. But you can rewrite your query using `configureQuery()` method and add all your OrderBy you want.

Comment: @GasKa I dont want more than one field for sorting, I just want each field to have its own sort direction, so when i click the date column sort button for the first time it sorts descendant and when i click the name coolumn sort button for the first time it sort ascendant

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to make it work although it's not very fancy. In the SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/base_list.html.twig template, right after the sort parameters are created

```
{% set sort_parameters = admin.modelmanager.sortparameters(field_description, admin.datagrid) %}
```

I added this code:

```
{% set sortFilters = sort_parameters['filter'] %}
{% set sortFilters = sortFilters|merge({'_sort_order': field_description.options._sort_order}) %}
{% set sort_parameters = sort_parameters|merge({'filter': sortFilters}) %}
```

now the only thing I have to do is tell the field in the Admin the sort_order, like this:

```
$listMapper->
    ->add('sent', null, [
        '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
        ...
```

there is no need to put ASC, since it's the default value.

As I said before: not fancy nor I like it very much, but it works for me.